# WSO2 API manager OAuth scope definition at Application Level

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

We just started evaluating WSO2 API Manager and found a potential feature missing in the product or may be with some tweak this may be achievable, so looking for some guidance on the below.

1. We define User Role and associate a User with that Role.
2. Create an API on API Publisher and define resource scopes mapping to Role
   defined in above step
3. Generated Token specifying the scope defined in above Step and able to consume the API with access_token having the right scope

> $APIM_ENDPOINT/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&username=VENDOR_USER1&password=VENDOR_PASS1&scope=scope_customer_creation scope_transaction_query scope_rates_query scope_product_query

**Challenge**
For large implementations where we have 3000+ APIs with different resources (GET/PUT/DELETE), defining of different scope for each of this APIs is not practical. And Secondly, when subscribing the APIs (currently 50+ subscribers), it would be impractical for them to specify so many scopes on the Auth Token generation Endpoint.
And the major issue here is if a new API is released with a new scope, API subscriber has to generate a new access_token including new scope which makes it impractical again as the token is cached on their end as per SLA default - **15 minutes**. Reducing the token duration would require change on all the API subscriber end and also will increase the API calls for token fetch which doesn't make any sense.

**Approach/Suggestion**
Is there a way to define these scopes at Application level instead of per API resource? So that we can create a User & Role and associate that role to the application and not the individual APIs. In that way we can add as many APIs to Role or Scope and associate it with subscriber's application only.

So in total we only have to define 50 Roles/Scope and assign APIs to these scopes as per subscribers need. So the total permutation will be reduced, and any new addition of API will not require fetching of new token as the existing token will have only 1 fixed scope defined at application level and we can just add this API to the Role.